# Javascript: Nested for loop to printout 2D array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am having problem in printing 2D array in nested for loop. I created objects, methods, array and arrays of object in javascript and now I want to display values by using for loop and 2D array. I tried the method I know but I am not getting output as per my expectation. Can anyone please help me ?

```
code:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title> Trial </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function item(item_name, item_taste, item_description) {
            this.name = item_name;
            this.taste = item_taste;
            this.description = item_description;    
            this.display = displayClass;
        }

        function displayClass(){
            document.documentElement.className = 'js';
            document.write(this.name);
            document.write(this.taste);
            document.write(this.item_description);
            document.write('<br />');
            }

            var myItem = new item("Pani Puri", "Spicy", "Crispy shells, Potatoes & Onions Served with sweet & chilled Tangy mintwater");   
            var myItem2 = new item("Aloo Tikki", "Spicy", "2 Whole Wheat Fried Breads Served With Potato Curry");  
            var myItem3 = new item("Papri chat", "Spicy", "Homemade chips, lentil dumplings, garbanzo bean, potato yogurt, chutney, onion & spices");

            var myItem4 = new item("Chicken Palak", "Meduim Spicy", "Boneless Chicken Cooked In Hot Spicy Sauce With Potatoes");
            var myItem5 = new item ("Chicken Korma", "Meduim Spicy", "Chicken In A Mild Creamy Sauce & Cashew Nuts");
            var myItem6 = new item("Chicken Masala", "Spicy", "Bite Sized Chicken Cooked In An Onion Based Sauce");

            var myItem7 = new item("Kheer", "Sweet", " Indian Rice Pudding Spiced With Cardamom");
            var myItem8 = new item("Rasmalai", "Sweet", "Made From Homemade Style Fresh Cheese In Sweetned Milk" );
            var myItem9 = new item("Gulab Jamun", "Sweet", "Sweet Round Shaped Pastry Fried & Soaked In Flavored Syrup");


            property = new Array("Varieties", "Taste", "Item Description");
            category = new Array("Chaats", "Chicken", "Dessert");

            chaats = new Array(myItem, myItem2, myItem3);
            chicken = new Array(myItem4, myItem5, myItem6);
            dessert = new Array(myItem7, myItem8, myItem9);

            var cat = new Array(chaats, chicken, dessert);

        </script>
       </head>
       <body>
        <table border="4", align="center", cellpadding="5", cellspacing="5" >            
           <thead>
                <tr>
                    <script type="text/javascript">                        
                           for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                           document.write('<th>'+ property[i] +'</th>'); }

                    </script>
                </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {       
                            document.write("<th><tr>"  + category[j] + "</tr></th>");
                         for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                            document.write("<td>" + cat[j][k] + "</td>");
                         }
                        }
                    </script>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Expected Output:

[image]

output:

[image]

Comment: it's not `"<th><tr>"  + category[j] + "</tr></th>"` tr is the tablerow and is defined before the **t**able**h**ead tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `[object Object]` because this is the value of any object's `toString()`. For example, if you type this into the JavaScript console in Dev tools, you'll see:

```
> var myObject = {hello: 'world'}
> myObject.toString()
"[object Object]"
```

You need to add a definition for `item.prototype.toString` to  determine how you would like to display these objects. For example, you can use this snippet:

```
item.prototype.toString = function (category){
  return  '<tr><th>' + 
    category + ' </th><td>' +
    this.name + ' </td><td>' +
    this.taste + '</td><td>' +
    this.description + '</td></tr>';
}
```

And then modify the last script tag to have:

```
                    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                      for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                        document.write( cat[j][k] ); // calls our item.toString() method
                      }
                    }
```

For a final result looking like the following (click Run code snippet to see output):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title> Trial </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function item(item_name, item_taste, item_description) {
            this.name = item_name;
            this.taste = item_taste;
            this.description = item_description;    
            this.display = displayClass;
        }

item.prototype.toString = function (category){
  return  '<tr><th>' + 
    category + ' </th><td>' +
    this.name + ' </td><td>' +
    this.taste + '</td><td>' +
    this.description + '</td></tr>';
}

        function displayClass(){
            document.documentElement.className = 'js';
            document.write(this.name);
            document.write(this.taste);
            document.write(this.item_description);
            document.write('<br />');
            }

            var myItem = new item("Pani Puri", "Spicy", "Crispy shells, Potatoes & Onions Served with sweet & chilled Tangy mintwater");   
            var myItem2 = new item("Aloo Tikki", "Spicy", "2 Whole Wheat Fried Breads Served With Potato Curry");  
            var myItem3 = new item("Papri chat", "Spicy", "Homemade chips, lentil dumplings, garbanzo bean, potato yogurt, chutney, onion & spices");

            var myItem4 = new item("Chicken Palak", "Meduim Spicy", "Boneless Chicken Cooked In Hot Spicy Sauce With Potatoes");
            var myItem5 = new item ("Chicken Korma", "Meduim Spicy", "Chicken In A Mild Creamy Sauce & Cashew Nuts");
            var myItem6 = new item("Chicken Masala", "Spicy", "Bite Sized Chicken Cooked In An Onion Based Sauce");

            var myItem7 = new item("Kheer", "Sweet", " Indian Rice Pudding Spiced With Cardamom");
            var myItem8 = new item("Rasmalai", "Sweet", "Made From Homemade Style Fresh Cheese In Sweetned Milk" );
            var myItem9 = new item("Gulab Jamun", "Sweet", "Sweet Round Shaped Pastry Fried & Soaked In Flavored Syrup");


            property = new Array("Varieties", "Taste", "Item Description");
            category = new Array("Chaats", "Chicken", "Dessert");

            chaats = new Array(myItem, myItem2, myItem3);
            chicken = new Array(myItem4, myItem5, myItem6);
            dessert = new Array(myItem7, myItem8, myItem9);

            var cat = new Array(chaats, chicken, dessert);

        </script>
       </head>
       <body>
        <table border="4", align="center", cellpadding="5", cellspacing="5" >            
           <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th></th>
                    <script type="text/javascript">                        
                           for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                             document.write('<th>'+ property[i] +'</th>'); }

                    </script>
                </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {       
                            // document.write("<tr><th colspan='3'>"  + category[j] + "</th></tr>");
                         for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                            document.write( cat[j][k].toString(category[j]) );
                         }
                        }
                    </script>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I was told to use simple for loop and print values. I can't use JSON...Can you please suggest me in the way I code ?

Comment: Thank you so much @Julian. But Can I get item name in same row...for e.g. item name chaats in same row as pani puri....item name chicken in same row as chicken palak like that ?

Comment: If you need the category printed in the first column, then why not pass it into `toString(category)` and modify the method accordingly? Honestly, no one in the world knows what you're trying to make this page look like except for you. I've answered your original question quite sufficiently, so if you need further help please ask a new question...

Comment: Your code was very helpful to me. Thank you very much but I only need bit change. I posted expected output screenshot above. Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you very very much...you saved my day